# How to determine if my passenger is using apache or nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a rails project for the first time with Passenger. I've followed the guide on Passenger's site with the passenger gem and used 'passenger-install-apache2-module' and pasted the three lines into my httpd.conf. However, I noticed that when I tried to run passenger start in my project directory, it tried install passenger for nginx again, and when that finished, I was able to do 'passenger start'. The issue that I've noticed is that when I removed the three lines from my httpd.conf I was still able to run 'passenger start and seemingly to have started the server. My question hence becomes how would I determine if my passenger gem was installed for apache or nginx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'passenger start' does not use your apache or nginx installation.  It uses it's own in built webserver which is based on nginx.  It starts on port 3000 by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so why is the guide telling me to do passenger-install-apache2-module in that case then? Does it actually do anything in this case?

Comment: 'passenger start' is used to quickly get a development environment up and running.   passenger-install-apache2-module installs a module used for your Apache installation so that you can host Rails applications.